# Safari 8.0.7 non-functional on newly installed 10.10.4

Tags: safari

Safari 8.0.7 became non-functional immediately after I attempted to make a simple preference change regarding what newly opened windows displayed.

I tried everything up to and including, just now:

• the more extensive hardware test available on one of the original install discs of my MacBook Pro (results: ‘No trouble found.’)

• complete reinstall of OSX 10.10.4

Everything appears fine after the system re-install, except no change to Safari 8.0.7; it continues to hang on startup (repeatedly, after the system re-install); no access to top menu, no other option than to force quit.

I had zero extensions running on Safari 8.0.7 prior to the problem; in fact had extensions turned off then and prior to the system reinstall.

(Among other efforts prior to the system reinstall I just completed, I had installed Safari 9.0 [beta], as a result of a suggestion posted here in late 2014; that also had no effect.)

---

response to first answer and first comment below:

Buscar웃SD:

Thanks for your help.

I can’t access the Safari application at all, so unless there’s another way to do it, I don’t believe I can clear the cache (which I am familiar with, and do regularly, most recently probably within a day or two prior to the program becoming useless).

I am 100% certain that I had zero extensions and zero plug-ins installed, but you reminded me (in the unlikely event of this info being of any use): I believe the program hung immediately after I had attempted to make a simple preferences change related to what new windows displayed; however, it could have been immediately after I used the slider button to turn Safari extensions off (since it was an option, and I had no extensions, I had figured: why not?); if not immediately prior, I had done this in very close proximity to the program becoming permanently unresponsive.

I just installed the ‘OSX Yosemite 10.10.4 Combo Update’. No change to Safari (though you didn’t indicate there would be, I figured possibly worth checking prior to responding here).

Regarding your question:

‘Could we see your console log?’

Certainly, but I’m sorry I have no idea what to produce here and how.

Keeping in mind that I cannot access the Safari application at all, I’m assuming that you are referring to the program (which I’m not at all familiar with) at:

Applications > Utilities > Console

I don’t see an export function, and there seem to be a number of options of what to send. If you could give me some simple instructions, I’ll take care of this ASAP.

---

response to **third comment** below:

*Now find the time stamp when you tried to start Safari (assume you made a note of that)*

Buscar웃SD:

As much as I document, I didn’t document that detail, but assuming simply doing it again serves this purpose, I **launched Safari** at 7:24:00 (< exactly, or within a second) and **force quit** at 7:25:10.

Here’s the Console entries (which I made more easily readable by deleting the date that was added to each upon copying, and inserting paragraph breaks):

```
7:24:03.656 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.

7:24:04.176 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.

 7:25:12.359 PM CoreServicesUIAgent[282]: unexpected message <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x7fff7d0f8c60> { count = 1, contents =
    "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x7fff7d0f8f70> { length = 18, contents = "Connection invalid" }
}>

7:25:12.363 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.WebKit.Networking.1D381AA6-3F95-46E8-826B-5BDFBF78C84A[7011]) Service exited with abnormal code: 1

7:25:12.457 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.Safari.15368[7006]) Service exited due to signal: Terminated: 15

7:25:21.429 PM spindump[351]: Saved hang report for Safari version 8.0.7 (10600.7.12) to /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Safari_2015-07-25-192521_apples-MacBook-Pro.hang

7:25:21.598 PM Problem Reporter[7174]: Failed to connect (_imageWell) outlet from (ProblemReportWindowController) to (NSImageView): missing setter or instance variable

7:25:22.398 PM system_profiler[7178]: platformPluginDictionary: Can't get X86PlatformPlugin, return value 0

7:25:22.399 PM system_profiler[7178]: platformPluginDictionary: Can't get X86PlatformPlugin, return value 0

7:25:22.521 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
```

---

(Please IGNORE if a 7.2 MB Bookmarks.plist would have zero to do with this.)

Buscar웃SD:

In the (hopefully unlikely) event this has anything to do with this:

My Safari Bookmarks.plist is 7.2 MB. Using Vienna RSS reader (after I lost the integrated reader from 10.6.8), I look at (title and source) approximately 6000 articles monthly coming from about 500 RSS feeds. I read, or at least skim, somewhere between 500 and 1000 articles per month, and (in almost all cases after adding the date — YYMMDD —  to the front of the default name about to be bookmarked), I probably bookmark about  250 articles per month, in subfolders sometimes up to five levels deep. I’ve never spent the time to learn how to determine how many bookmarks I have, and always assumed these consumed a tiny amount of space, but a wild guess would be 10,000. All of these are accessible through about 20 folders (named with one or two characters so they easily fit) in the header bar.

Comment: could we see your console log, it might say something about that (for the time stamp of interest only) = when you start Safari. Also a question to you: did you install the combo update ? https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1820?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Comment: Buscar웃SD: I responded above to your comment and Answer by editing my original post, as my response is more readable with the paragraph breaks intact and it appears to me that comments don't support paragraph breaks.

Comment: sorry for that. I newer know the skilz of the OP. Open Application Folder the the Utility then Click on the Console. Now find the time stamp when you tried to start Safari (assume you made a note of that). Select lines you want to copy by holding "shift" key, now press cmd+c. Back here in your post press cmd+v to paste.

Comment: Buscar웃SD: I've provided the Console data as an edit at bottom of the original post.

Comment: Buscar웃SD: I just added a brief comment regarding my 7.2 MB Safari Bookmarks.plist to the bottom of the original post.

Comment: Since you have so many, I would suggest you make a copy and save them in another place, just in case. Copy and save the Bookmarks.plist, which is located at ~/Library/Safari/

Comment: Luckily your OS X has saved a report on Safari problems in /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Safari_2015-07-25-192521_apples-MacBook-Pro.hang Do you know how to upload files to Dropbox or similar service?

Comment: "Do you know how to upload files to Dropbox or similar service?" Yes, I use DropBox fairly regularly (and, incidentally, regarding my Bookmarks.plist: though I could easily — though it would consume some time — prune thousands of older bookmarks from it, I consider that the most irreplaceable file on my computer, and have the Safari folder as an item in my Finder window sidebar so that I can save it regularly in a few seconds, even though doing so is mostly redundant to Time Machine and BackBlaze incremental backups).

Comment: good to know you are taking care of your most valuables. I will be waiting for you to upload the "Safari_2015-07-25-192521_apples-MacBook-Pro.hang" so I can take look what is it saying.

Comment: Late to the party, but have you tried trashing the saved state yet? Trash the entirety of  ~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Safari.savedState It only loses the 'last opened' state, nothing vital

Comment: Buscar웃SD: Sorry, I’m sometimes too literal. I answered your question that I knew how to do this, but didn’t do it as you didn’t explicitly instruct me to (but what would have been the point of the question otherwise  ;-) ).

That file is at:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3fmk1li0wan0cis/Safari_2015-07-25-192521_apples-MacBook-Pro.hang?dl=0

(I’ve found DropBox glitchy; I just tested the link by emailing it to myself.)

Comment: Tetsujin: I assume you’re referring to the hidden library accessible by holding down option while dropping down the ‘Go’ menu from the Finder. I don’t see that file, top-level or otherwise, to the folder, ‘Saved Application State.’ Incidentally (perhaps): I’m not at all familiar with that folder, but aliases there, none of which are functional (‘…the original item for…can’t be found.’) seem odd to me. Here’s a snapshot of top-level to that folder: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ja9qd425unvkabd/150726-0431%20Saved%20Application%20State.png?dl=0  .

Comment: Noting this only in the event it provides a clue to the Safari problem: I just installed a software update for my printer (found while hoping to find a Safari fix  ;-) ), but I needed to click through about 15 error messages (I snapshotted 7). Except for the remainder of the file name following System/Library/Extensions/, they were all identical to the first:  >  >  >
System extension cannot be used
The system extension “/System/Library/Extensions/BJSBP2Driver.kext” was installed improperly and cannot be used. Please try reinstalling it, or contact the product’s vendor for an update.<  <  <